# How do I make a list of type for each Pokemon name in SwiftUI if the list in a array?

Tags: json, swift, listview, swiftui

I have everything correct up to the point where I am trying to access the type in a list. This the view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(pokedex) { section in
                Section(header: Text(section.name.english)) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("HP:")
                        Text("\(section.base.hp)")
                        Text("Attack:")
                        Text("\(section.base.attack)")
                        Text(section.type.bug)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            
            
        }
        
        
        
    }
}
```

This is the model:

```
// MARK: - PokeDexElement
struct PokeDexElement: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: Name
    var type: [TypeElement]
    var base: Base

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case name = "name"
        case type = "type"
        case base = "base"
    }
}

// MARK: - Base
struct Base: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var hp: Int
    var attack: Int
    var defense: Int
    var spAttack: Int
    var spDefense: Int
    var speed: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case hp = "HP"
        case attack = "Attack"
        case defense = "Defense"
        case spAttack = "Sp. Attack"
        case spDefense = "Sp. Defense"
        case speed = "Speed"
    }
}

// MARK: - Name
struct Name: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var english: String
    var japanese: String
    var chinese: String
    var french: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case english = "english"
        case japanese = "japanese"
        case chinese = "chinese"
        case french = "french"
    }
}

enum TypeElement: String, Codable {
    case bug = "Bug"
    case dark = "Dark"
    case dragon = "Dragon"
    case electric = "Electric"
    case fairy = "Fairy"
    case fighting = "Fighting"
    case fire = "Fire"
    case flying = "Flying"
    case ghost = "Ghost"
    case grass = "Grass"
    case ground = "Ground"
    case ice = "Ice"
    case normal = "Normal"
    case poison = "Poison"
    case psychic = "Psychic"
    case rock = "Rock"
    case steel = "Steel"
    case water = "Water"
}

typealias PokeDex = [PokeDexElement]
```

This is the JSON:
[{
"id": 1,
"name": {
"english": "Bulbasaur",
"japanese": "フシギダネ",
"chinese": "妙蛙种子",
"french": "Bulbizarre"
},
"type": [
"Grass",
"Poison"
],
"base": {
"HP": 45,
"Attack": 49,
"Defense": 49,
"Sp. Attack": 65,
"Sp. Defense": 65,
"Speed": 45
}
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": {
"english": "Ivysaur",
"japanese": "フシギソウ",
"chinese": "妙蛙草",
"french": "Herbizarre"
},
"type": [
"Grass",
"Poison"
],
"base": {
"HP": 60,
"Attack": 62,
"Defense": 63,
"Sp. Attack": 80,
"Sp. Defense": 80,
"Speed": 60
}
},
{
"id": 3,
"name": {
"english": "Venusaur",
"japanese": "フシギバナ",
"chinese": "妙蛙花",
"french": "Florizarre"
},
This is the json

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": {
      "english": "Bulbasaur",
      "japanese": "フシギダネ",
      "chinese": "妙蛙种子",
      "french": "Bulbizarre"
    },
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 45,
      "Attack": 49,
      "Defense": 49,
      "Sp. Attack": 65,
      "Sp. Defense": 65,
      "Speed": 45
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": {
      "english": "Ivysaur",
      "japanese": "フシギソウ",
      "chinese": "妙蛙草",
      "french": "Herbizarre"
    },
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison"
    ],
    "base": {
      "HP": 60,
      "Attack": 62,
      "Defense": 63,
      "Sp. Attack": 80,
      "Sp. Defense": 80,
      "Speed": 60
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": {
      "english": "Venusaur",
      "japanese": "フシギバナ",
      "chinese": "妙蛙花",
      "french": "Florizarre"
    },
```

Comment: In the same way as you iterated pokemons

Comment: I get this error: Value of type '[TypeElement]' has no member 'bug'. I don't if I can access the values inside [TypeElement] the same way, since TypeElement is also type enum.